# Production of sulfuric acid using sulfur dioxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment, hydrolysis

Is it possible to create sulfuric acid using sulfur dioxide directly dissolved in water? Usually, people oxidize the $\ce{SO2}$ to sulfur trioxide ($\ce{SO3}$) first. If this is possible, why is it not done industrially?

Comment: see [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34138/preparation-of-sulfuric-acid-through-contact-process) and [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47588/where-does-the-sulfuric-acid-used-in-contact-process-for-manufacturing-sulfuric?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to dissolve sulfur dioxide into water, you'll get sulfurous acid instead of sulfuric acid: $$\ce{H2O + SO2 <=> H+ + HSO3-}$$

There's a [very good reading material on the Contact Process](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/equilibria/contact.html) to help explain why we have opted for the specific industrial conditions.

Comment: Sulfurous acid does not exist. It is an aqueous solution of sulfur dioxide.