Synthesis of Sulfuric Acid via Sulfurous Acid Oxidation
I was planning on bubbling sulfur dioxide fumes into water to produce sulfurous acid ($\ce{H2SO3}$) and was wondering if it could be oxidized into sulfuric acid. How could it be oxidized into $\ce{H2SO4}$? Could bubbling oxygen into sulfurous acid work to produce sulfuric acid?
I'm new to chemistry and appreciate the help I can get.

See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152100/can-physical-absorption-happen-despite-the-formation-of-products and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53493/production-of-sulfuric-acid-using-sulfur-dioxide

Speculatively, absorption in diluted hydrogen peroxide solution to produce diluted H2SO4 could work. But it is not a way to produce concentrated H2SO4.

If you want to produce a diluted solution of sulfuric acid, you may first dissolve $\ce{SO2}$ into water then oxidize by air or any other oxidant. This will give you diluted sulfuric acid in water. Evaporation of all water is nearly impossible. You cannot obtain pure anhydrous sulfuric acid by this method. The only way of obtaining pure sulfuric acid is using the same reactions without water, in the gas state, or in a solvent made of previously prepared anhydrous sulfuric acid. This technique is well described in all chemistry books.
